# Triplets don't seem to add up

Tags: piano, notation, rhythm

I am starting to teach myself Piano and I have some background in music from school, but I don't remember much.  I am working on a new song that has, what I believe to be, a triplet.

From what I understand, triplets that are all the same type of note take up 2 beats instead of 3 (in the case of quarter notes).  However, this measure seems to me to only add up to 3 beats and not 4.  Do I only play 3 beats for the whole note below it, or is the triplet tied to the whole note on the next line?  Or is this not a triplet?

[image: Last Measure of the First Line]

The measure in question has 1 quarter rest followed by 3 quarter notes with what looks like a triplet symbol over it.  I notice that it uses a curved line instead of a square bracket though so I'm not sure.

Comment: Modern notation practices will always use a square bracket or beam for tuplet notation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a triplet.

The arc is a phrase mark and the 3 is the fingering of the note on the third beat. Together they kind of look like a triplet, but you can tell it is not a triplet because the arc is continued in the next measure confirming it is a phrase mark.

Comment: Or to be more specific legato phrasing marks. I was wondering myself if the three was not just a fingering indication.

Comment: Another way you can tell that it's not a triplet is that fingering numbers are upright and triplet 3s (and other numbers for irregular groups) are italic.